# Wolfram Engine 13.3.0 dies, is this a bug?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, bugs

$ wolframscript

Wolfram Language 13.3.0 Engine for Linux x86 (64-bit)
Copyright 1988-2023 Wolfram Research, Inc.

```
Minimize[{2 Pi (b - 0.305 + R) (0.305 + R),-(b*Pi*(0.305^2 - R^2)*7850) == 13000},{b,R}]
```

"The Wolfram Engine exited because an error occurred. For a Wolfram Engine older than 12.1, this can mean that the product is not yet activated."

If i try the same with different values of the constraint, like 18000 or 19000 instead of 13000 it works as expected.

Comment: If it crashes is a bug, crashing is never the intended behaviour.
However, I can NOT reproduce your problem :
`Wolfram Language 13.3.0 Engine for Microsoft Windows (64-bit)
Copyright 1988-2023 Wolfram Research, Inc.
In[1]:= Minimize[{2 Pi (b - 0.305 + R) (0.305 + R),-(b*Pi*(0.305^2 - R^2)*7850) == 13000},{b,R}]
NMinimize::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations.
Out[1]= {10.1884, {b -> 1.00811, R -> 0.784808}}
In[2]:= $Version
Out[2]= 13.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 12, 2023)
 `

Comment: Thank You for testing. I have Linux version of W Engine and it crashes every time. Or at least i tried five times and rebooted pc once between the tries.

Comment: Let's hope somebody with Linux and Engine 13.3.0 can test it further.

Comment: One possibility is that run away recursion leads to an out of memory condition, which might crash Mathematica

Comment: Ok. I have abt 40 gigs of memory. I run top in another window and wolframscript in another window. I did not noticed any big memory consumption. Minimize crashed in less than one second.

Comment: If this crashes, please send it to the support, such that WRI ca fix the issue .

Comment: I have submitted bug report now. They can analyze better if it is a real bug: "A support case with the identification [CASE:5097243] was created."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR:  A workaround may be to add the constraint `b>0`.

I am running Wolfram Language 13.3.0 Engine for Linux x86 (64-bit) in a docker container.  It was installed using `docker pull wolframresearch/wolframengine`.  When I start Wolfram Engine (using `/usr/bin/wolframscript`) and paste your code in at the In[1]: prompt, Wolfram Engine crashes back to my shell prompt without an error message.

If I start Wolfram Engine with the "-print all" option, then I get the error message quoted in the OP.

When I add the `b>0` to the OP code, Wolfram Engine emits "Out[1]= {10.0303, {b -> 0.817575, R -> 0.858943}}" and gives me an input prompt (no crash).

Here is a Wolfram Language script (minimize.wl) and its output.

```
$Version
"MemoryAvailable"/.("Machine"/.First@SystemInformation[])

"\nTry with the b>0 constraint.  This gives a numeric answer."
Minimize[{2 Pi (b - 0.305 + R) (0.305 + R),-(b*Pi*(0.305^2 - R^2)*7850) == 13000, b>0},{b,R}]

"\nTry the original.  This crashes."
Minimize[{2 Pi (b - 0.305 + R) (0.305 + R),-(b*Pi*(0.305^2 - R^2)*7850) == 13000},{b,R}]
```

The output from `wolframscript -print all -file minimize.wl`:

```
(*
13.3.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (June 12, 2023)
Quantity[11.694656372070312, Gibibytes]

Try with the b>0 constraint.  This gives a numeric answer.
{10.030272964481549, {b -> 0.8175746560509296, R -> 0.8589426638564431}}

Try the original.  This crashes.

NMinimize::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations.
{10.18844443215304, {b -> 1.0081077965956742, R -> 0.7848075171467485}}
*)
```